# Why query with "in" and "on" statement runs infinitely

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have three tables, table3 is bascially the intermediate table of table1 and table2. When I execute the query statement that contains "in" and joins table1 and table3, it just kept running and I could not get the result. If I use `id=134` instead of `id in (134,267,390,4234 ... )`, the result comes up. I don't understand why "in" has the effect, does anyone have an idea?

Query statement:

```
select count(*) from table1, table3 on id=table3.table1_id where table3.table2_id = 123 and id in (134,267,390,4234) and item = 30;
```

table structure:

```
table1:
   id integer primary key,
   item integer
   
table2:
   id integer,
   item integer

table3:
    table1_id integer,
    table2_id integer

-- the DB without index was 0.8 TB after the three indices is now 2.5 TB
indices on: table1.item, table3.table1_id, table3.table2_id
```

env: Linux, sqlite 3.7.17

Comment: Your query does not compile. `Error: no such column: table3.table1.id` I assume you meant `table3.table1_id`.

Comment: The FROM clause should be `from table1 inner join table3 on table1.id = table3.table1_id` OR with aliases: `from table1 t1 inner join table3 t3 on t1.id = t3.table1_id`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes While I agree it's better to make the join explicit, `from table1, table3 on id=table3.table1_id` and `from table1 inner join table3 on id=table3.table1.id` are equivalent in SQLite. See [Side note: Special handling of CROSS JOIN.](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

Comment: @Schwern Oh, sorry, the query statement was wrong, I revised it

Answer (score 1):

`from table1, table3` is a [cross join](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php) on most databases, with the size of your data a cross join is enormous, but in SQLite3 it's an inner join. From the [SQLite SELECT docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

> **Side note: Special handling of CROSS JOIN.** There is no difference between the "INNER JOIN", "JOIN" and "," join operators. They are completely interchangeable in SQLite.

That's not your problem in this specific instance, but let's not tempt fate; always write out your joins explicitly.

```
select count(*)
from table1
join table3 on id=table3.table1_id
where table3.table2_id = 123
  and id in (134,267,390,4234);
```

Since you're just counting, you don't need any data from table1 but the ID. table3 has table1_id, so there's no need to join with table1. We can do this entirely with the table3 join table.

```
select count(*)
from table3
where table2_id = 123
  and table1_id in (134,267,390,4234);
```

SQLite can only use one index per table. For this to be performant on such a large data set, you need a *composite index* of both columns: `table3(table1_id, table2_id)`. Presumably you don't want duplicates, so this should take the form of a unique index. That will cover queries for just table1_id and queries for both table1_id and table2_id; you should drop your table1_id index to save space and time.

```
create unique index table3_unique on table3(table1_id, table2_id);
```

The composite index will not for queries which use only table2_id, keep your existing table2_id index.

Your query should now run lickity-split.

For more, read about the [SQLite Query Optimizer](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html).

---

A terabyte is *a lot* of data. While [SQLite technicly can handle this](https://sqlite.org/limits.html), it might not be the best choice. It's great for small and simple databases, but it's missing a lot of features. You should look into a more powerful database such as [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/). It is not a magic bullet, all the same principles apply, but it is much more appropriate for data at that scale.

Comment: I am actually not sure, if sqlite3 reacts better than just using file system, I mean, simply reads all files. I am really struggling in determinding which database I should take, MangoDB or file system or postgresql. I wrote the application description in this post before, but nobody answered my futher questions, could you please have a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62409573/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-read-several-lines-of-data-from-a-large-file/62504425#62504425

Comment: @ErwinZangwill You definitely do not want to use the filesystem, you'll wind up reimplementing SQLite poorly. Just getting concurrent access correct is very, very hard. MongoDB and NoSQL are fine for storing "documents". Postgres has the best of both worlds: it's a very featureful SQL database but also supports JSON columns where more flexibility is needed. You also do not want to do this in C, it is the most difficult language to develop software in and your performance problems will be in the database.

Comment: @ErwinZangwill Most databases support some sort of CSV import tool. The size and performance of the import does not matter; who cares if it takes a week, you're only going to do it once. The important thing is to get it right, both the conversion and the schema. A language like Python or Ruby or Go would be more appropriate than C. Without knowing what your data looks like, I can't say more.

Comment: Thanks a loot!! I read that MangDB or some nosql database use mmap to pre-load files into memory, since my RAM is no big enough to load all the file into memory, I don't know if it would perform better than sqlite or even postgresql? Also, the MangoDB stores json file, but aren't the names of attributes redundancy? I don't really understand why it doesn't just store the header?

Comment: btw. "SQLite can only use one index per table", so a table can have multiple indices but when executing queries, only one indices will be used for one query?  ans as for "That will cover queries for just table1_id and queries for both table1_id and table2_id", "The composite index will not for queries which use only table2_id, keep your existing table2_id index" why it will keep the `table1_id` index but not `table2_id`? Actually, for the further processing, both `table1_id`, `table2_id` will be used for queries respectively, so the two indices `table2_id` and `table3_unique` are needed right?

Comment: @ErwinZangwill You're thinking at way, way, way too low a level. SQL databases have had 50 years to do optimizations. None of them store simple files. Database optimization is not like code optimization. Before you tackle terabytes of data, you should probably do some exercises with smaller data sets.

Comment: @ErwinZangwill Yes, SQL dbs will typically choose use one index per query per table. Some can use multiple, but infrequently as the value of an index drops rapidly when you have to merge them. For more on composite indexes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60804492/14660

Comment: hey, I finally created the composite index it took more than one week... I revised the query statement in the question description, which it did connect to one attribute of table1. But unfortunately, there was still nothing came out with the query statement. Was it actully just due to the large data set?

Comment: I noticed that, if I let the query run for 20 mins, and make the sqlite3 timer on and  after that, interrupt the query by 'ctrl+c', it showed 'CPU 0.5...s USR 0.4...s', this means that the database focused on I/O right, but I don't know why this happened, since I already set the 'cache_size' to 500000 and 'page_size' 4096 which outcomes 2GB cache, where htop showed that the mem usage was 10GB (200gb RAM avaliable).

Comment: Without knowing your query and dataset I can't say what's wrong, and I'm guessing you did not post your real query. Again, a multi-terabyte database is not where you should be beginning to work with SQL. I would suggest starting with a much smaller data set, getting that working, and then working up to your full data set. The turn around time for experimenting will be much faster.

Comment: hey, that was actually pretty much the real query, I just change the names of attributes, so it would be easier to understand. I did tried with small dataset, that worked without any problem. The row data was indeed 700GB, importing them to database tables make it 1T, with the three indices on table3, that is now 3.5T.